# Consuming RSS filed by several clients and avoid duplicate processing

Tags: rss

Soppose the following scenario :

Some system generates a RSS feed with all updated or new items it has .

Other system must consume this feed and performe some action with each item from this feed.

So far so good .

Now  I want to put more than one consuming service at the same time , for example for performance issue and for scalling .

What will be the best way to avoid of the same item being proceseed on more than one consuming service ?

Comment: Do you have control of only the consuming system, or do you also have control of the system publishing the RSS?

Comment: both systems on design stage , so it is possible to change them both. What i am doing is the consuming system.

Comment: I'm sure there are some very elegant ways to sync the consuming services which would answer your question specifically as asked, but it might also be worthwhile to look at something on the publishing side to ensure uniqueness of what is passed to a consumer in any given request (ex. a querystring parameter). Then you just have to worry about one publisher doing the coordination among many consumers.